# How are PPP, nominal exchange rates and inflation related?

Tags: macroeconomics, inflation, exchange-rates, international-economics, purchasing-power-partity

This [Forbes article](https://www.forbes.com/sites/stevehanke/2018/04/25/the-ins-and-outs-of-venezuelas-hyperinflation-spotlights-on-the-imf-and-the-financial-press/#444db604103c) discusses how changes in the market exchange rate can be used to estimate an inflation rate thanks to the principle of purchasing power parity (PPP).

Can someone distill this process a little better? I can follow the steps mentioned in the article, but the underlying principles are still not clear to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $P$ denote the price in the home country, $E$ represent units
of domestic currency used to buy one unit of foreign currency, and
$P^{*}$ represent the price level in the foreign country. Now, PPP
implies that:
$$
P=EP^{*}
$$
 In other words, prices when expressed in the same currency are equalized
across countries. Log-differentiate and take changes and obtain:
$$
\hat{P}=\hat{E}+\hat{P}^{*}
$$
 where hats denote changes. Rearrange, and find that:
$$
\hat{E}=\hat{P}-\hat{P}^{*}
$$
In other words, the changes in exchange rate inform one of relative changes
in price levels (inflation). This is what is know as **relative PPP**

Comment: Thank you for this. Is this 'relative' PPP, the PPP that is approximated by The Economist's Big Mac index?

Comment: Relative PPP just expresses PPP in changes. From what I understand, the Big Mac  Index still express prices in levels.